# find the difference on fields between records when using Format with Multiple Columns in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to find a way of finding the difference on a fields between records when using Format with Multiple Columns. 
Example. Each column represents a different record per client

`Column 1     Column 2  Change
      1           4         3

      3           2        -1`

etc

I can put the output(change value) in the group footer. 
 Will also at times have more columns then just two.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try below approach:

1. Create a formula `@Column1`

   ```
   Local NumberVar a;
   a:=Column1;
   ```
2. Create a formula `@Column2`

   ```
   Local NumberVar b;
   b:=Column2;
   ```
3. Create a formula `@difference`

   ```
   EvaluateAfter({@Column1});
   EvaluateAfter({@Column2});

   {@Column2}-{@Column1}
   ```

Place formula `@difference` to the righmost part of the report and firs two to left part of the report.

Comment: I have tested code before giving answer...it woked for me....where r u getting problem?